# Query performance degrades 50 times after a few records are deleted

Tags: php, mysql, database

I got 3 tables: articles, categories and relations.

An article can be assigned to more than one category, and relations table is in charge of tracking that. And one more thing to note, articles table has a longtext type field: article_content. And the indexes of the tables are articles.article_id, categories.category_id, relations.relations_id. For the articles table, there is another index (article_title, article_content), but I don’t it would be used in this case.

The problematic query is like:

```
SELECT COUNT(articles.article_id) 
FROM articles, relations, categories 
WHERE relations.article_id=articles.article_id AND 
     (relations.category_id=categories.category_id) AND 
      relations.category_id=1566 AND 
      article_status IN ('approved','featured') AND 
     (article_expiry_date='0000-00-00' OR article_expiry_date >= now())
```

There’re initially 21k records in articles, 1.9k records in categories and 25k records in relations table. The time used to run the query is about 0.0019 second.

What I need to do is deleting articles, relations, categories records which are in a specific categories. And within this categories, there are child categories and articles. So I run some query to get a list of the categories recursively and put the list in an array $tmp_array.  Then for each array, I deleted articles assigned to it, then delete the category itself and at last delete the relations, with a simplest query:

```
Foreach($tmp_array as $cat)
{
    $art_query1 = "DELETE phpkb_articles 
                  FROM phpkb_relations, phpkb_articles 
                  WHERE phpkb_relations.category_id = $cat AND
                        phpkb_articles.article_id = phpkb_relations.article_id";

    mysql_query($art_query1,$connection);

    $art_query2 = "DELETE phpkb_categories
                  FROM phpkb_categories
                  WHERE phpkb_categories.category_id = $cat";

    mysql_query($art_query2,$connection);

    $art_query3 = "DELETE phpkb_relations
                  FROM phpkb_relations
                  WHERE phpkb_relations.category_id = $cat";

    mysql_query($art_query3,$connection);
}
```

This goes well. And after the deletion, there are 19k records in articles, 1.6k records in categories and 22k records in relations table.

Then I run the problematic query again, now the time is about 0.1 seconds, almost 50 times worse than before. I have to run this query for likely thousands times so the result is a huge time difference.

Also, I’m very curious about why there is such kind of performance difference. As the query stays the same and the records number actually decreases, there is no reason for that.

Is there anything wrong about query or did the DB get messed up upon the deletion of records? Can anybody help to answer my questions? Thanks a lot!

Comment: After doing lots of deletions, try using `OPTIMIZE TABLE`.

Comment: @Barmar, the whole DB is about 500MB big. Would it be needed?

Comment: please show the table structures. As I do not see any point in query getting slow.

Comment: relations.category_id,categories.category_id,relations.category_id,categories.category_id,article_expiry_date are these columns indexed?

Comment: @Vickrant, no, only the primary keys are indexed. I think that's done by default.

Comment: @Barmar, I tried OPTIMIZE TABLE on all the 3 tables. Now the performance seems to be back to normal. Thanks! Any explanations on this though? :)

Comment: This is bad practice please index those fields which you are using for the joins or searching. This way your query will be very fast because indexing uses balanced tree for searching on that particular field which make things very fast.

Comment: @Vickrant Is probably right. Try adding an index on `article_expiry_date`.